# how to build a range aggregation on parent by minimum value in children docs

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent/child relationship created between `Product` and `Pricing` documents. A `Product` has many `Pricing`, each with it's own `subtotal` field, and I'd simply like to create a range aggregation that only considers the minimum subtotal for each product and filters out the others.

I think this is possible using nested aggregations and filters, but this is the closest I've gotten:

```
 POST /test_index/Product/_search
 {
   "aggs": {
     "offered-at": {
       "children": {
         "type": "Pricing"
       },
       "aggs": {
         "prices": {
           "aggs": {
             "min_price": {
               "min": {
                 "field": "subtotal"
               },
               "aggs": {
                 "min_price_buckets": {
                   "range": {
                     "field": "subtotal",
                     "ranges": [
                       {
                         "to": 100
                       },
                       {
                         "from": 100,
                         "to": 200
                       },
                       {
                         "from": 200
                       }
                     ]
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

However this results in the error `nested: AggregationInitializationException[Aggregator [min_price] of type [min] cannot accept sub-aggregations]; }]`, which sort of makes sense because once you reduce to a single value there is nothing left to aggregate.

But how can I structure this so that the range aggregation is only pulling the minimum value from each set of children?

(here is a sense with mappings and test data : http://sense.qbox.io/gist/01b072b4566ef6885113dc94a796f3bdc56f19a9)